# Android parse + stripe

Tags: android

I'm an amateur coder and just had a quick question regarding using stripe with parse on Android.

Using the Android example on the stripe site I've been able to generate a token fine but I'm lost when it comes to sending that token to the cloud code. I've done the cloud code but I can't work out how to send.

Also it doesn't like then token value. I can't convert it to a string.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Could you put your code here ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?..I am also facing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was sending the entire token instead of the toked Id. The cloud code requires a token id from your Android Client. You can get the token id by calling token.getId();

Here is the section of java code where you send the token Id:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("cardToken", token.getId());
```

Here is the section of cloud code where you receive the token Id:

```
card: request.params.cardToken
```

Here is an example Android Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.parse.FunctionCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseCloud;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.stripe.android.Stripe;
import com.stripe.android.TokenCallback;
import com.stripe.android.model.Card;
import com.stripe.android.model.Token;

import java.util.HashMap;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "Parse Key", "Parse Key");


        String cardNumber = "4242-4242-4242-4242";
        int cardExpMonth = 7;
        int cardExpYear = 2050;
        String cardCVC = "123";
        String key = "Stripe Test Publish Key";

        Card card = new Card(
                cardNumber,
                cardExpMonth,
                cardExpYear,
                cardCVC
        );

        card.validateNumber();
        card.validateCVC();

        if(!card.validateCard()){
            Log.d("Main Activity", "Invalid Card");
        }else{
            Log.d("Main Activity", "Card Created: " + cardNumber);
        }


        new Stripe().createToken(card, key, new TokenCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Main Activity", "Connection Failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                Log.d("Main Activity", "Purchase Successful!");
                Log.d("Main Activity", "17th August: " + token.getId());
                HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                params.put("cardToken", token.getId());
                ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("purchase", params, new FunctionCallback<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Object o, ParseException e) {
                        if(e == null){
                            Log.d("Main Activity","Cloud Response: " + o.toString());
                        }
                    }
                });


            }
        });



    }
```

Here is an example Cloud Function:

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('Stripe Test Secret Key');

Parse.Cloud.define("purchase", function(request, response) {

Stripe.Charges.create({
  amount: 100 * 1000, // $1000 expressed in cents
  currency: "usd",
  card: request.params.cardToken // the token id should be sent from the client
},{
  success: function(httpResponse) {
    response.success("Purchase made!");
  },
  error: function(httpResponse) {
    response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  }
});

});
```

Just replace the Parse Keys and Stripe Keys with your own.

Hope this helps!